# Refresh Listview after a dialog

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to create a Listview which refresh itself as soon as I press a certain button in my alert dialog. This is my code, which correctly loads the item as soon as I open the activity, but when I click on the negative button of the dialog it successfully does the operation inside it, but does not refresh the list. This is the code:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        user = loadUser();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arAd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.user_list,user);
        setListAdapter(arAd);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(UserList.this)
                        .setTitle("Gestisci test")
                        .setMessage("Scegli un'operazione")
                        .setPositiveButton("Apri test", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //to handle
                            }
                        })

                        .setNegativeButton("Elimina Test", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                File dir = new File("..");
                                dir.delete();
                                //Here I should refresh the list
                                arAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the item from the adapter after or before deleting the file and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, removing a file from the file system and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter won't refresh the list in the adapter